# Java formatting very large number every 3 digit

Tags: java

I made a class `Number` that handles operations on very very (infinite) large numbers. it can add, subtract, multiply, factorise etc.

I have an issue in the printing of a large number, "1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000" in this format. I have a `String` with a number like this one without spaces. Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong? Here's the code :

```
  public String show(){
     String res = "";
     int j = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < this.digits; i++) { 
         j++;
         if(j==4) {
            j=0;
            res+= " ";
         }
         //E[i] is the digit of the number
         res += this.E[i];
     }
     int j = 0;
     return res;
  }
```

I tried things with `if(i%4==0)` things like that it seems the space isn't working as I want it to.
Thanks in advance for your precious help :)

Comment: for one, you're returning `returner`, which isn't referenced anywhere else in the method's code.

Comment: `Number` is already an abstract class in `java.lang`.  Calling your class `Number` is asking for trouble, use a different name.

Comment: Just a comment: I'd use modulo (`i % 3 === 0`) - now you don't have to reset your counter.

Comment: its called nombre I just editted for here just to not confuse you
Yes i renamed vars for here

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will also group by 3 from the beginning, not the end. So `1000000` will become `100 000 0` and not `1 000 000`.

Comment: yes it would do that ^^

Comment: "that handles operations on very very (infinite....) large numbers" Can't you use `BigInteger`?? (append your num to a `StringBuilder`, reverse, insert space every 3 chars, reverse, enjoy)

Comment: No I need operations that arn't defined in BigInt I wanted to make my class to train somethings like polymorphisms ect...

Comment: @MaximeFleury it's easier to help if you tell us what you're getting as output, as well as desired output (you did the latter, not the former).

Comment: @MaximeFleury Try using `j=digits%3;`. This means the first group will take into account the string length and have the appropriate length to start with.

Comment: numberString = numberString.replaceAll("(\\d{3})", "$1 "); that doesn't work it gives me spaces at the end not at the write place

Comment: @Mörre it was suggested in the loop, I'm suggesting it for the initialisation.

Comment: @AntonH But he should not even need `j`. PS: I see only now that he sets it to ß again at the very end, uselessly... oh well.

Comment: what about [`(String.format("%,d", new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000"))).replace(',', ' ')`](https://ideone.com/YRyjou)

Comment: @Mörre I disagree. Using `i%3` in the loop would give him the same behaviour that OP currently has, grouping by groups of 3 from the beginning.

Comment: @AntonH All he has to do for right-to-left is reverse the direction of the `for` loop. Amazing how many comments such a tiny question can generate.

Comment: @Mörre That's another possibility, but not one I'm willing to code in a comment. I was working with his code, and gave a solution that would fit in a limited number of characters. If you want to write an answer with a reverse-loop (I suppose you mean counting down), go ahead. I might even upvote if it's good. I'll also add that OP wasn,t really clear in what wasn't working, but that's another kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you I opted for cheating using :

```
public String show(){

String res = "";
for (int i = 0; i < this.nbchiffres; i++) { 
    res += this.E[i];
    }
return (String.format("%,d", new BigInteger(res))).replace(',', ' ');
}
```

I didn't wanted to cheat this way, but since its working... thank you all :)